# Could not determine artifacts for androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2: No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Gradle Dependencies are:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.hendraanggrian.material:collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Gradle Project Sync failed every time after clean and rebuild.

Comment: are you conected to the internet?

Comment: Have you tried building it via terminal? Do it once and make sure post the command here that you used to build it.Also make sure you are connected to open network internet connection.

Comment: Android Studio is not connected to internet and in Preferences > Gradle "Offline work" is checked.

Comment: I got the same error using the terminal, but resolving with androd studio build it works

Answer (score 29):

- To resolve this issue please Turn off Gradle offline mode.
- Just go to (*android studio 3.6 and above*)

  **View -> Tool Window -> Gradle -> Toggle Offline Mode Icon**

  [Click here to see the Toggle Offline Mode Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Wax.png)

Comment: On new android studio, flag has moved inside gradle tab (on top right corner)

Comment: Thank you. My issue is resolved. Also had same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Gradle is in **offline mode**, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies.

```
Go to Preferences (File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment) -> Gradle and uncheck "Offline work".
```

Comment: Next 3 days I need to work in offline mode. Thats why I need to set checked the "Offline work" option.

Comment: Because of Check `Offline Work` this issue is raised. So disable and download first. After completing update you can enable again.

Comment: I was in a situation where internet connection was suddenly disconnected for next 3 days and there was no option to download first.

Comment: Disabling Offline work is not desired process but I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if *gradle global settings* is set to offline work ,android studio will not be able to resolve this for you
To Resolve this

1. Go to preferences
2. Build,Execution,Deployment
3. Gradle
4. Global gradle settings
5. Uncheck offline work
6. Then Rebuild your project/Try sync

> Make sure you have a working internet connection else possibly not work

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9hjx.png)

Go to build.gradle(:app) and change
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
to
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
as shown in the diagram

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings then search for gradle. Here are 2 status:

1. Your gradle is set to work offline(by checkbo
2. Your gradle path is not set correctly(if there wasn't problem before)

If all thing is ok then search proxy in setting page and check them. You can also check your connectivity here.

These 3 ways may solve the problem.